# JPEG XL error when installing PHP on macOS with brew

Tags: php, macos, operating-system, homebrew, jpeg-xl

```
cmake -S . -B build -DJPEGXL_FORCE_SYSTEM_BROTLI=ON -DJPEGXL_FORCE_SYSTEM_LC
==> cmake --build build

Last 15 lines from /Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/chatbox/Library/Logs/Homebrew/jpeg-xl/02.cmake:
cd /tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/build/lib && /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang++ -DHWY_DISABLED_TARGETS="(HWY_SVE|HWY_SVE2|HWY_SVE_256|HWY_SVE2_128|HWY_RVV)" -DJPEGXL_MAJOR_VERSION=0 -DJPEGXL_MINOR_VERSION=8 -DJPEGXL_PATCH_VERSION=1 -DJXL_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_BUILD -D__DATE__=\"redacted\" -D__TIMESTAMP__=\"redacted\" -D__TIME__=\"redacted\" -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1 -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/lib/include -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/build/lib/include -fno-rtti -funwind-tables -Xclang -mrelax-all -Xclang -mconstructor-aliases -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O3 -DNDEBUG -O2 -std=c++11 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -Wall -fmerge-all-constants -fno-builtin-fwrite -fno-builtin-fread -Wextra -Wc++11-compat -Warray-bounds -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-register -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-parameter -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wvla -Wdeprecated-increment-bool -Wfloat-overflow-conversion -Wfloat-zero-conversion -Wfor-loop-analysis -Wgnu-redeclared-enum -Winfinite-recursion -Wliteral-conversion -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -Wprivate-header -Wself-assign -Wstring-conversion -Wtautological-overlap-compare -Wthread-safety-analysis -Wundefined-func-template -Wunreachable-code -Wunused-comparison -fsized-deallocation -fno-exceptions -fmath-errno -fnew-alignment=8 -fno-cxx-exceptions -fno-slp-vectorize -fno-vectorize -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -DJPEGXL_ENABLE_TRANSCODE_JPEG=1 -DJPEGXL_ENABLE_BOXES=1 -MD -MT lib/CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/splines.cc.o -MF CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/splines.cc.o.d -o CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/splines.cc.o -c /tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/lib/jxl/splines.cc
[ 59%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/toc.cc.o
cd /tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/build/lib && /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang++ -DHWY_DISABLED_TARGETS="(HWY_SVE|HWY_SVE2|HWY_SVE_256|HWY_SVE2_128|HWY_RVV)" -DJPEGXL_MAJOR_VERSION=0 -DJPEGXL_MINOR_VERSION=8 -DJPEGXL_PATCH_VERSION=1 -DJXL_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_BUILD -D__DATE__=\"redacted\" -D__TIMESTAMP__=\"redacted\" -D__TIME__=\"redacted\" -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1 -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/lib/include -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/build/lib/include -fno-rtti -funwind-tables -Xclang -mrelax-all -Xclang -mconstructor-aliases -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O3 -DNDEBUG -O2 -std=c++11 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -Wall -fmerge-all-constants -fno-builtin-fwrite -fno-builtin-fread -Wextra -Wc++11-compat -Warray-bounds -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-register -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-parameter -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wvla -Wdeprecated-increment-bool -Wfloat-overflow-conversion -Wfloat-zero-conversion -Wfor-loop-analysis -Wgnu-redeclared-enum -Winfinite-recursion -Wliteral-conversion -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -Wprivate-header -Wself-assign -Wstring-conversion -Wtautological-overlap-compare -Wthread-safety-analysis -Wundefined-func-template -Wunreachable-code -Wunused-comparison -fsized-deallocation -fno-exceptions -fmath-errno -fnew-alignment=8 -fno-cxx-exceptions -fno-slp-vectorize -fno-vectorize -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -DJPEGXL_ENABLE_TRANSCODE_JPEG=1 -DJPEGXL_ENABLE_BOXES=1 -MD -MT lib/CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/toc.cc.o -MF CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/toc.cc.o.d -o CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/toc.cc.o -c /tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/lib/jxl/toc.cc
[ 60%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/decode_to_jpeg.cc.o
cd /tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/build/lib && /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang++ -DHWY_DISABLED_TARGETS="(HWY_SVE|HWY_SVE2|HWY_SVE_256|HWY_SVE2_128|HWY_RVV)" -DJPEGXL_MAJOR_VERSION=0 -DJPEGXL_MINOR_VERSION=8 -DJPEGXL_PATCH_VERSION=1 -DJXL_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_BUILD -D__DATE__=\"redacted\" -D__TIMESTAMP__=\"redacted\" -D__TIME__=\"redacted\" -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1 -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/lib/include -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/build/lib/include -fno-rtti -funwind-tables -Xclang -mrelax-all -Xclang -mconstructor-aliases -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O3 -DNDEBUG -O2 -std=c++11 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -Wall -fmerge-all-constants -fno-builtin-fwrite -fno-builtin-fread -Wextra -Wc++11-compat -Warray-bounds -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-register -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-parameter -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wvla -Wdeprecated-increment-bool -Wfloat-overflow-conversion -Wfloat-zero-conversion -Wfor-loop-analysis -Wgnu-redeclared-enum -Winfinite-recursion -Wliteral-conversion -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -Wprivate-header -Wself-assign -Wstring-conversion -Wtautological-overlap-compare -Wthread-safety-analysis -Wundefined-func-template -Wunreachable-code -Wunused-comparison -fsized-deallocation -fno-exceptions -fmath-errno -fnew-alignment=8 -fno-cxx-exceptions -fno-slp-vectorize -fno-vectorize -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -DJPEGXL_ENABLE_TRANSCODE_JPEG=1 -DJPEGXL_ENABLE_BOXES=1 -MD -MT lib/CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/decode_to_jpeg.cc.o -MF CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/decode_to_jpeg.cc.o.d -o CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/decode_to_jpeg.cc.o -c /tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/lib/jxl/decode_to_jpeg.cc
[ 60%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/box_content_decoder.cc.o
cd /tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/build/lib && /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang++ -DHWY_DISABLED_TARGETS="(HWY_SVE|HWY_SVE2|HWY_SVE_256|HWY_SVE2_128|HWY_RVV)" -DJPEGXL_MAJOR_VERSION=0 -DJPEGXL_MINOR_VERSION=8 -DJPEGXL_PATCH_VERSION=1 -DJXL_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_BUILD -D__DATE__=\"redacted\" -D__TIMESTAMP__=\"redacted\" -D__TIME__=\"redacted\" -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1 -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/lib/include -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/build/lib/include -fno-rtti -funwind-tables -Xclang -mrelax-all -Xclang -mconstructor-aliases -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O3 -DNDEBUG -O2 -std=c++11 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -Wall -fmerge-all-constants -fno-builtin-fwrite -fno-builtin-fread -Wextra -Wc++11-compat -Warray-bounds -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-register -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-parameter -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wvla -Wdeprecated-increment-bool -Wfloat-overflow-conversion -Wfloat-zero-conversion -Wfor-loop-analysis -Wgnu-redeclared-enum -Winfinite-recursion -Wliteral-conversion -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -Wprivate-header -Wself-assign -Wstring-conversion -Wtautological-overlap-compare -Wthread-safety-analysis -Wundefined-func-template -Wunreachable-code -Wunused-comparison -fsized-deallocation -fno-exceptions -fmath-errno -fnew-alignment=8 -fno-cxx-exceptions -fno-slp-vectorize -fno-vectorize -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -DJPEGXL_ENABLE_TRANSCODE_JPEG=1 -DJPEGXL_ENABLE_BOXES=1 -MD -MT lib/CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/box_content_decoder.cc.o -MF CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/box_content_decoder.cc.o.d -o CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/box_content_decoder.cc.o -c /tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/lib/jxl/box_content_decoder.cc
[ 60%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/jpeg/dec_jpeg_data.cc.o
cd /tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/build/lib && /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang++ -DHWY_DISABLED_TARGETS="(HWY_SVE|HWY_SVE2|HWY_SVE_256|HWY_SVE2_128|HWY_RVV)" -DJPEGXL_MAJOR_VERSION=0 -DJPEGXL_MINOR_VERSION=8 -DJPEGXL_PATCH_VERSION=1 -DJXL_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_BUILD -D__DATE__=\"redacted\" -D__TIMESTAMP__=\"redacted\" -D__TIME__=\"redacted\" -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1 -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/lib/include -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/build/lib/include -fno-rtti -funwind-tables -Xclang -mrelax-all -Xclang -mconstructor-aliases -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O3 -DNDEBUG -O2 -std=c++11 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -Wall -fmerge-all-constants -fno-builtin-fwrite -fno-builtin-fread -Wextra -Wc++11-compat -Warray-bounds -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-register -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-parameter -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wvla -Wdeprecated-increment-bool -Wfloat-overflow-conversion -Wfloat-zero-conversion -Wfor-loop-analysis -Wgnu-redeclared-enum -Winfinite-recursion -Wliteral-conversion -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -Wprivate-header -Wself-assign -Wstring-conversion -Wtautological-overlap-compare -Wthread-safety-analysis -Wundefined-func-template -Wunreachable-code -Wunused-comparison -fsized-deallocation -fno-exceptions -fmath-errno -fnew-alignment=8 -fno-cxx-exceptions -fno-slp-vectorize -fno-vectorize -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -DJPEGXL_ENABLE_TRANSCODE_JPEG=1 -DJPEGXL_ENABLE_BOXES=1 -MD -MT lib/CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/jpeg/dec_jpeg_data.cc.o -MF CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/jpeg/dec_jpeg_data.cc.o.d -o CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/jpeg/dec_jpeg_data.cc.o -c /tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/lib/jxl/jpeg/dec_jpeg_data.cc
[ 61%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/jpeg/dec_jpeg_data_writer.cc.o
cd /tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/build/lib && /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang++ -DHWY_DISABLED_TARGETS="(HWY_SVE|HWY_SVE2|HWY_SVE_256|HWY_SVE2_128|HWY_RVV)" -DJPEGXL_MAJOR_VERSION=0 -DJPEGXL_MINOR_VERSION=8 -DJPEGXL_PATCH_VERSION=1 -DJXL_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_BUILD -D__DATE__=\"redacted\" -D__TIMESTAMP__=\"redacted\" -D__TIME__=\"redacted\" -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1 -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/lib/include -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/build/lib/include -fno-rtti -funwind-tables -Xclang -mrelax-all -Xclang -mconstructor-aliases -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O3 -DNDEBUG -O2 -std=c++11 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -Wall -fmerge-all-constants -fno-builtin-fwrite -fno-builtin-fread -Wextra -Wc++11-compat -Warray-bounds -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-register -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-parameter -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wvla -Wdeprecated-increment-bool -Wfloat-overflow-conversion -Wfloat-zero-conversion -Wfor-loop-analysis -Wgnu-redeclared-enum -Winfinite-recursion -Wliteral-conversion -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -Wprivate-header -Wself-assign -Wstring-conversion -Wtautological-overlap-compare -Wthread-safety-analysis -Wundefined-func-template -Wunreachable-code -Wunused-comparison -fsized-deallocation -fno-exceptions -fmath-errno -fnew-alignment=8 -fno-cxx-exceptions -fno-slp-vectorize -fno-vectorize -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -DJPEGXL_ENABLE_TRANSCODE_JPEG=1 -DJPEGXL_ENABLE_BOXES=1 -MD -MT lib/CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/jpeg/dec_jpeg_data_writer.cc.o -MF CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/jpeg/dec_jpeg_data_writer.cc.o.d -o CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/jpeg/dec_jpeg_data_writer.cc.o -c /tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/lib/jxl/jpeg/dec_jpeg_data_writer.cc
[ 61%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/jpeg/jpeg_data.cc.o
cd /tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/build/lib && /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang++ -DHWY_DISABLED_TARGETS="(HWY_SVE|HWY_SVE2|HWY_SVE_256|HWY_SVE2_128|HWY_RVV)" -DJPEGXL_MAJOR_VERSION=0 -DJPEGXL_MINOR_VERSION=8 -DJPEGXL_PATCH_VERSION=1 -DJXL_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_BUILD -D__DATE__=\"redacted\" -D__TIMESTAMP__=\"redacted\" -D__TIME__=\"redacted\" -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1 -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/lib/include -I/tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/build/lib/include -fno-rtti -funwind-tables -Xclang -mrelax-all -Xclang -mconstructor-aliases -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O3 -DNDEBUG -O2 -std=c++11 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -Wall -fmerge-all-constants -fno-builtin-fwrite -fno-builtin-fread -Wextra -Wc++11-compat -Warray-bounds -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-register -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-parameter -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wvla -Wdeprecated-increment-bool -Wfloat-overflow-conversion -Wfloat-zero-conversion -Wfor-loop-analysis -Wgnu-redeclared-enum -Winfinite-recursion -Wliteral-conversion -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -Wprivate-header -Wself-assign -Wstring-conversion -Wtautological-overlap-compare -Wthread-safety-analysis -Wundefined-func-template -Wunreachable-code -Wunused-comparison -fsized-deallocation -fno-exceptions -fmath-errno -fnew-alignment=8 -fno-cxx-exceptions -fno-slp-vectorize -fno-vectorize -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -DJPEGXL_ENABLE_TRANSCODE_JPEG=1 -DJPEGXL_ENABLE_BOXES=1 -MD -MT lib/CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/jpeg/jpeg_data.cc.o -MF CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/jpeg/jpeg_data.cc.o.d -o CMakeFiles/jxl_dec-obj.dir/jxl/jpeg/jpeg_data.cc.o -c /tmp/jpeg-xl-20230419-31426-1xmzz11/libjxl-0.8.1/lib/jxl/jpeg/jpeg_data.cc
[ 61%] Built target jxl_dec-obj
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I did uninstall an earlier version of PHP and when I run `brew install php`, everything seems to work fine until JPEG XL section which gives an error

Comment: You've shared the progress output. But you haven't shared the actual error message. There should be some error message output (either to the screen or in log file). Please try to find out and share them.

Comment: That was the output given, where can I find these error logs? which folder?

Comment: i did check , updated my os, remove mac ports packages and reinstalled and everything worked well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrading to Mac OS Big Sur Fixed this issue for me